# jqModal trigger a second modal window from a link inside the first modal

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I'm trying to do a two steps modal window. The first is a form with a submit button, once you click it, it should close the modal, and open a second modal window with different content and design. I can't use jquery hide/show to toggle different divs because in this case the second modal is totally different.
If I do this, it doesn't work

`$('#callLink').click(function(){
    $('#jqAgenda').jqmHide();
    $('#jqConfirm').jqmShow();
});`

callLink is inside jqAgenda modal window

Thanks

---

This worked fine, the overlay stays on the background while the new modal window is being loaded.

`$('#callLink').click(function(){ 
    $('#jqAgenda').jqmHide(); 
}); 
$('#jqCall').jqm({trigger: '#callLink'});`

Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

It has a onhide event where you can bind a function when your current modal is closed.

```
onHide (callback)
Called when a dialog is to be hidden. Be sure to remove the overlay (if enabled).
// onHide : fade the window out, remove overlay after fade. 

    var myClose=function() { 
     //open a new modal here
    };


$('#dialog').jqm({onHide:myClose}); 

//(function|false) - default: false
```

If not working try to bind click function to modals close button or anything that closes it when clicked

Comment: Thanks Ronel, I've been trying with that callback with no luck, I was able to accomplish what I was looking for with this code
`$('#callLink').click(function(){
    $('#jqAgenda').jqmHide();
});
 
$('#jqCall').jqm({trigger: '#callPolice'});`